# How to handle unpredictable shells in swtbot

Tags: swtbot

In my RCP Application, sometimes some shell are opening on some conditions and i want to handle them.
for example: Overwrite shell will open if file is already exist in folder.I want to work on Overwrite shell if it would open.

I have tried if condition with shell is active,see code. But if condition is not working in swtbot. It is trying to click on Ok button which is on Overwrite shell even if overwrite shell is not opening.

See code:

```
if (swtBot.shell("Overwrite").isActive) {   
    swtBot.Button("Ok").click(); //This code is every time executing even if Overwrite shell is not opened.
} else {   
    //doing some other operation
}
```

Comment: I removed the [tag:shell] tag because this seems to be about something quite different.

Comment: What about using `SWTBotShell.isOpen()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {   
swtBot.Button("Ok").click(); // it will click the button if the appropriate shell is active
} catch(WidgetNotFoundException e) {   
//doing some other operation
}
```